# Printing a hidden table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, printing

I have a page with one table, that is paginated, showing only 10 entries per page, and I need to print to paper the entire table at once, so I've made one hidden table, without pagination and with all the entries, and I'm trying to print it with Print.js, but the printing preview always show a blank page. I've already tried `@media print` but it doesn't work at all.

CSS:

```
.printable {
    display: none;
}

@media print {
    .printable {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

PHP page:

```
    <div id="relatPrint" class="printable">
        <div class="card">        
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Relatórios de Envio</h5>                
                <hr>                     
                <table class="table table-striped table-responsive w-100 d-block d-md-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>                        
                            <th scope="col">ID</th>
                            <th scope="col">Código de Envio</th>
                            <th scope="col">Mensagem de envio</th>
                            <th scope="col">Data de envio</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>                    
                        <?php foreach($envios as $envio): ?>                    
                            <tr>                                                     
                                <td><?= esc($envio->id) ?></td>
                                <td><?= esc($envio->codigo) ?></td>
                                <td><?= esc($envio->log) ?></td>
                                <td><?= esc($envio->data) ?></td>                            
                            </tr>                        
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the printing script:

```
function printRelat(){
    printJS('relatPrint', 'html')
}
```

Comment: Can you try putting the css into a style tag within the table? I think it's not working because print.js copies the element and places it into a hidden iframe.

Comment: I can try it. I actually solved it by doing the display change by jQuery. But I don't see how I could put a media query in a inline style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the issue by entirely doing the display handling by jQuery and totally forgetting the CSS.

PHP now is:

```
<div id="relatPrint" class="printable" style="display: none">
        <div class="card">        
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Relatórios de Envio</h5>                
                <hr>                     
                <table class="table table-striped table-responsive w-100 d-block d-md-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>                        
                            <th scope="col">ID</th>
                            <th scope="col">Código de Envio</th>
                            <th scope="col">Mensagem de envio</th>
                            <th scope="col">Data de envio</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>                    
                        <?php foreach($envios as $envio): ?>                    
                            <tr>                                                     
                                <td><?= esc($envio->id) ?></td>
                                <td><?= esc($envio->codigo) ?></td>
                                <td><?= esc($envio->log) ?></td>
                                <td><?= esc($envio->data) ?></td>                            
                            </tr>                        
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the script:

```
function printRelat(){
    $('.printable').css('display', 'block');
    printJS('relatPrint', 'html');
    $('.printable').css('display', 'none');
}
```